# Proving a property of convex quadrilateral and the Thales-circle via the Pigeonhole Principle

Tags: geometry, pigeonhole-principle, quadrilateral

I'm asked to prove the following:

In a convex quadrilateral, the Thales circle of every side, (meaning the half circle, where the side is the diameter) is drawn. Prove that the four half-circles cover the entire quadrilateral.

I am given the hint that I should use the Pigeonhole Principle to prove this. However I have never applied the Pigeonhole Principle to Geometry and don't know where to start. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If not using Pigeonhole Principle, the solution is in 3 lines.

Comment: @NN2 if so, could you show me the proof without the Pigeonhole Principle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the convex quadrilateral $ABCD$. Let's $O$ any point inside $ABCD$.

We have $\widehat{AOB}+\widehat{BOC}+\widehat{COD}+\widehat{DOA} = 360°$ then there exists an angle (WOLG, suppose $\widehat{AOB}$) less than or equal to $90°$.

Because $\widehat{AOB}\le 90$ then $O$ must inside the circle where its diameter is the side $AB$.